# How can I use bst file with my .bib (bibtex) file?

Tags: bibtex, texworks, elsarticle, bst

I am very new to latex and I know this question might sound rather noobish or even stupid. First time I got my hands on TeX, after reading a tutorial online, I inserted `\bibliography{reference}` and `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` at the end of the .tex file. I used `\cite{label}` notation in the text. TeXworks read the content of the `reference.bib` file and managed the whole citing thing without bothering me! Now I am trying to write my first manuscript using latex. I downloaded the template file from Elsevier's website. This template uses a `.bst` file and `\bibitem[ ()]{}` in the text. I can't understand why we need this `\bibitem` thing and why the TeXworks won't just read the references from `.bib` file and insert them in the text using `\cite{}`.

here is a [link](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0007/56842/elsarticle-template.zip) to the template

P.S: I guess the problem is that for Elsevier I have to use the `.bst` file in order to have references formated as Elsevier requires. And, this .bts file uses `natbib` package which has this weird (at least to me) things called `\bibitem{}`. I read the documentation of natbib package and still can't see why they use this `\bibitme{}` things instead of fetching the references from the `.bibtex` file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you have a question about a publisher template, I would suggest to ask your publisher contact. However and despite I do not know the template you've loaded (can you please add a link to your question?): Maybe they are using a `thebibliography` environment only for example. Maybe this is even copied from a generated `bbl` file (or have you even looked into the `bbl` file?) Maybe the template supports different journals and even several build methods. Maybe just the template author knows the answer.

Comment: texworks is just a text editor it is not responsible for any processing. You need to run pdflatex then bibtex then pdflatex twice to use bibtex on a bst style. You may have those set up as separate menu options, or the whole sequnce as a single one, or type the commands on the command line.

Comment: @cabohah thank you very much for your nice comment. Yes, it uses `\thebibliography` environment.  Here is a [link](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0007/56842/elsarticle-template.zip) to the template (added to the question as well). I guess this is the way `natbib` package works. but I still can't see why one would use this `\bibitem` thing and add copy and paste the references one by one.

Comment: The comments in the template files explain it: Use either `\bibliographystyle{…}` and `\bibliography{…}` and additionally run `bibtex` or use `\begin{thebibliography}{…}\bibitem…\end{thebibliography}` and don't need to tun `bibtex` but have to do the formatting of the entries on your own. You have the choice of what you like better.

Comment: @cabohah thank you very much. I changed it and now it works!